# Protected attribute array declaration is always on a newline, but I want it on the same line

Tags: phpstorm, coding-style

The code after automatic formatting with <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> looks like this:

```
class ExampleModel extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'table1';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $casts
        = [  //array declaration is on a newline!
            'id' => 'int',
            'aa' => 'int',
            'bb' => 'int',
            'cc' => 'int',
        ];

    protected $fillable
        = [ //array declaration is on a newline!
            'id',
            'aa',
            'bb',
            'cc',
        ];
}
```

But I would like PhpStorm to let it be / keep on the same line:

```
class ExampleModel extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'table1';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $casts = [
            'id' => 'int',
            'aa' => 'int',
            'bb' => 'int',
            'cc' => 'int',
        ];

    protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'aa',
            'bb',
            'cc',
        ];
}
```

I thought it was under ***Editor > Code Style > PHP > Array initializer*** but nothing seems to work.

**attachment** ([link](https://mega.nz/#!ZkZBGSBD!Dm3Rj-bnmAXVnn56VBgXlffLx_27mwj-FCQc79aDcXQ))

```
<code_scheme name="PSR-2" version="173">
  <option name="AUTODETECT_INDENTS" value="false" />
  <option name="LINE_SEPARATOR" value="&#xA;" />
  <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="500" />
  <option name="SOFT_MARGINS" value="100" />
  <HTMLCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="HTML_KEEP_BLANK_LINES" value="1" />
  </HTMLCodeStyleSettings>
  <JSCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="FORCE_SEMICOLON_STYLE" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_GENERATOR_MULT" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_FUNCTION_LEFT_PARENTH" value="false" />
    <option name="USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES" value="false" />
    <option name="FORCE_QUOTE_STYlE" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACES_WITHIN_IMPORTS" value="true" />
  </JSCodeStyleSettings>
  <PHPCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="ALIGN_KEY_VALUE_PAIRS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_PHPDOC_PARAM_NAMES" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_PHPDOC_COMMENTS" value="true" />
    <option name="COMMA_AFTER_LAST_ARRAY_ELEMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="PHPDOC_BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_TAGS" value="true" />
    <option name="PHPDOC_BLANK_LINES_AROUND_PARAMETERS" value="true" />
    <option name="GROUP_USE_WRAP" value="0" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_BOOLEAN_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_NULL_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="ELSE_IF_STYLE" value="COMBINE" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RETURN_STATEMENT" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_RPAREN_AND_LBRACE_ON_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="FORCE_SHORT_DECLARATION_ARRAY_STYLE" value="true" />
    <option name="IF_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
  </PHPCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="HTML">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JavaScript">
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_METHOD_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_SIGNS_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_BLOCKS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_SIMPLE_METHODS_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="PHP">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="999" />
    <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_CONTROL_STATEMENT_IN_ONE_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_PACKAGE" value="1" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS" value="false" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_FOR" value="false" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="2" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_SIGN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="FOR_STATEMENT_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="FOR_STATEMENT_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="FOR_STATEMENT_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_RBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ASSIGNMENT_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="PLACE_ASSIGNMENT_SIGN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="FOR_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="SOFT_MARGINS" value="100" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="SCSS">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="Twig">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: Export and share your Code Style. It must be there. Another Q: how customized it is? Maybe you can just use "Set from..." and use Default one and then again to use another schema (PSR-x for example)?

Comment: You should have left some comment about your updates ... otherwise no notifications and I may have never come back to this question again...

Comment: @LazyOne duely noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `Wrapping and Braces` tab

You have checked **`Assignment statement | Assignment sign on next line`** option. Uncheck it to have desired formatting.

[image]